# Why isn't autocorrection enabled in my alert view text field ? (and how to enable it ?)

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an alert view :

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Place the pin", message: "Aditional details", preferredStyle: .Alert)
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ajouter", style: .Default) {
(_:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in 

 }

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: « Cancel », style: .Default) {
                    (_:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
}

alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler() { (_:UITextField!) -> Void in }
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
alert.addAction(saveAction)

presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**But I don't understand why autocorrect isn't enabled in the text field of the alert? How can I enable it?

Thank you.**

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had to specify it explicitly, so I replaced:

```
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler() { (_:UITextField!) -> Void in }
```

With :

```
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler() { (textField:UITextField!) -> Void in  textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.Yes }
```